# datetimepicker jumps back to 1899 on focus, how can I fix it?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using date time picker http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ to select date and time. However, there is something weird is happening when I click on the input field to select the data. the input field will show a value dated back to 1899. I am not sure why it is doing this.

Please note that I am creating these inputs "on the fly" using ajax request. The following is how I created those inputs

```
            var new_code = returnMeetingDuration('newCall_onCalendar', 'onCalendar[]', 0, min_val, max_val, min_val);
            $('#listNextCallDates').append('<input type="text" value="" name="triggerOn[]" class="triggerOnPicker" readonly="readonly" style="width: 175px;">' +
                                           '<input type="hidden" name="engine_ids[]" value="outbound" />' +
                                           '<div style="display:block; margin: 5px;">'+
                                           '<input type="checkbox" id="isAppointment" name="isAppointment[]" value="outbound" /> Make an appointment</div>'+
                                           '<div style="display:block; margin: 5px;">' +
                                           '<input type="checkbox" id="calendarAddBox" name="calendarAdd[]" value="outbound" />Add to my Calendar</div>' + new_code);
```

Then I generate the dattimepicker using the following codes

```
            $('.triggerOnPicker').datetimepicker({
                timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                stepMinute: 5,
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                HourMin: 5,
                HourMax: 17,
                minDate: 0
            });
```

I have tried this code but it is not working.

```
            $('.triggerOnPicker').datetimepicker({
                timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                stepMinute: 5,
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                HourMin: 5,
                HourMax: 17,
                minDate: 0
            }).on('focus', function(){
                $(this).not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker();
            });
```

it seems that it automatically select a date. I don't want it to automatically select a date. so if the input already has a value don't change it on the click.

The weird thing is that it works correctly and sometimes it does not. Can someone help me with this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and this  worked for me:

```
$('.triggerOnPicker').datetimepicker({
                timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                stepMinute: 5,
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                HourMin: 5,
                HourMax: 17,
                minDate: 0
            })**.datepicker('show');**
```

Comment: This did not work. infact when I added .datepicker('show'); it displaied the selector automatilcy for me which I don't want and also it selected the values back to 1899

Answer (score 0):

adding `useCurrent:false` fixed it for me.

```
$('.triggerOnPicker').datetimepicker({
useCurrent:false
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue. I just updated the format and removed the extra spaces to make it work.

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:00P",
                autoclose: true
            });
```